# Expression within shell script

Tags: bash

I have just seen this code, but i can't get my head around how this code can actually work. For my understanding it shoud just echo out everything, or am I wrong?

```
deleteOldDumps(){

local SYSTEM="$1"
echo "cd data; export PWD=\$(pwd); \
        for f in \${PWD}/*.dmp.*.gz; do
                if [ -e "$f" ]; then
                        rm -f *.dmp.*.gz
                        echo "removing $f"
                else
                        echo "Dumps do not exist"
                fi
        done \
"
}
```

Many thanks in advance
Rgds

Comment: Unless there is a global `$f` elsewhere in the script, the `$f` will be substituted with an empty string before the text is  echoed. Anyway, there's really no need for the while loop: the glob pattern will only return files that exist, so this will suffice: `echo 'rm -f ./data/*.dmp.*.gz'`

Comment: @glennjackman actually the default setting for shells is to return the glob pattern if it doesn't match any files, so in this case testing $f to be a file makes sense as the correct message "Dumps do not exist" can be given. However I don't see the point of the encompassing echo., and the nested use of double quotes doesn't result in correct code... Perhaps the output of the function is to be piped to a shell e.g. over ssh. The `SYSTEM` variable isn't used either, so this is probably incomplete.

Comment: Hi, the code is indeed incomplete. Here is another example where the code is nested in a quoted echo. My question again: Why would it allow this to be exectuded? `loadDumps(){
  export SYSTEM="$1"
  export DBSERVER="$2"
  export DATABASE="$3"
  export DUMPSNAME="$4"
  echo "export SYBASE=/usr/local/sybase;
        cd data;export PWD=\$(pwd);chmod 777 .; \
        /usr/local/sybase/bin/dbload -Database ${DATABASE} -Server ${DBSERVER} \
        -File \${PWD}/${DUMPSNAME}.dmp -Number 10 -Online -Kill -Z \
  " | ssh ${DBSERVER} bash -
}
`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the additional code. Code dumps in comment are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question just prints out the (expanded) contents to stdout.

But we do not see how that output gets *used*. It might get *redirected* somewhere -- we would need to see the *call* to `deleteOldDumps()` for that. (It could also be globally redirected via `exec`, or in the call of the script itself.)

The code in your comment shows a use case for `echo`ing code: It pipes the output to `ssh ${DBSERVER} bash -`, i.e. the code gets *executed* on a bash running on `${DBSERVER}`.